# Multi CEP Remetente - Magento

Tags: magento

Preciso saber se existe algum módulo para Magento, onde possibilite ter dois ou mais Centros de Distribuição e calcular o frete usando distintos CEP's remetentes.

Por exemplo:

```
se for produto X = cep1
se for produto Y = cep2
```

Comment: Recomendo fazer o [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site, e tentar ser mais especifico em sua pergunta, como está não sei se alguém poderá te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa de um método de envio customizado.

Tente criar o seu, de uma olhada nessa wiki do magento que me ajudou muito.

[aqui](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module)

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, porém, faço um pouco de idéia do que vc está querendo de acordo com o que perguntou.
Procure a página que vc está querendo aplicar essa modificação, lá você pode trabalhar com Javascript ou Jquery, em questões de simplicidades vou te dar um código em JS.

Basicamente se sua idéia é fazer a troca do cep de acordo com o tipo de produto, vc pode receber o valor desse produto por exemplo se ele estiver em um input, mas se não, você só tem que pegar esse elemento, do HTML que ele estiver e usálo. Segue o exemplo.

```
       function trigger_cep(x, y){ 
       // Receba o valor do produto pelo ID aqui
          var produto = document.getElementById('produto').value;
          if(produto == produto_x){
       // De acordo com o tipo de produto altere o cep aqui
          document.getElementById('cep').value = cep1;
          } else if(produto == produto_y) {
       // mesma coisa se o cep for y ele troca para o teu cep 2....
          document.getElementById('cep).value = cep2;        
         }
```

Entendeu, você pode utilizar o JS para manipular os elementos do front e trabalhar com eles, mas se não for isso que você quer, você então deve estar querendo algo mais pro backend, qualquer coisa fale ai, abraços.